# Is it correct to write "Request to Help" as a subject line for an email?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I sent an email to the IT Dept. to ask for a technical help. I had googled some suggestions for a suitable subject line and found "Request to help...". I used it, but then I thought it was not be correct to use the preposition "to". Could it be possible?

Comment: "Request to help" suggests that you're offering to help (them). I suggest that you change the subject line to state what it is that you need help with rather than just a generic 'please help' subject line.

Comment: "Request **for** help" is what you need: you are making a request for someone's help.

Comment: I likely would have used "Request for assistance".

Comment: Help Request, shorter and better.

Answer (score 1):

They will definitely understand it, but “for help” is correct. As it’s an email subject, try something simple like "Help Request: printer jam" or similar.